# selecting list value by index number using selenium java

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, selenium, webdriver

I tried using the `select()` method in my code, but Eclipse is showing an error. Is `select()` an inbuilt method of Selenium? I don't get it.

```
select(driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='webLossReport.contact.address.state']")),index=i);
```

Eclipse says `"The method select(WebElement, int) is undefined for the type entry"` and it is giving me an option to create a method in this class.

Please let me know how others are using it. My requirement is to "select a list value based on Index number"

Update: Code Posted as requested,

```
WebElement LSD = driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='webLossReport.lossInformation.locationOfLoss.state']"));
List <WebElement> LLS = LossStateDropdown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

int i= LLS.size();      
select(driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='webLossReport.contact.address.state']")),index=i);
```

Comment: Can you post all your code please?

Answer (score 3):

You're somehow lost between Selenium RC and Selenium WebDriver. Assuming you want to use WebDriver, [see this doc, it explains it all](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#user-input-filling-in-forms).

You can either do the following - it directly finds the third `<option>` tag in the specified `<select>` and clicks it:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('selectsId')/option[3]")).click();
```

or this using the [`Select` class](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html):

```
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selectsId")));
sel.selectByIndex(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, I solved using this:

```
selenium.Select("id=yourID", "index=" + i.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this library, but [the Selenium reference page](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#select%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) gives the following signature for `select`:

`select(java.lang.String selectLocator, java.lang.String optionLocator)`

In your code, the second argument is `index=i` which is assigning `index` to the value of `i`, and then returning that `int`. What string were you planning on passing as the second argument? `"index=i"`? `"index=" + i`?

Comment: yes even i referred the selenium reference page. if i directly give      "index=i" then eclipse says "index" is not a variable defined. i tried "index="+i also but it didn't work.