# How to locate a dropdown from div?

Tags: c#, javascript, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Below is some html code.

```
<div id="ServiceTypeId_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 389px;">
<a class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">
<span>Choose an Option</span>
<div>
<b></b>
</div>
```

Upon clicking the dropdown the list pops up.

[image: i am trying to click and select the value]

I'm trying to locate an element with the C# code below:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@Id='ServiceTypeId_chzn']")).Click();
```

But I'm unable to locate it.

Comment: Not in your code. Try posting more than 3 lines.

Comment: you want me to write whole code???

Comment: How do you know you can not locate the element, do you have a listener for the click event of ServiceTypeId_chzn?

Comment: I am new to selenium have no idea about listener. and how to apply this.

Comment: Hello Sir,Solution could be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442905/selecting-list-value-by-index-number-using-selenium-java

Comment: The standard webdriver select won't work with jQuery dropdowns as the underlying select element is hidden and webdriver will complain that the select is not visible. The way we deal with these is to click the container to expose the input field and then use sendkeys to enter a string that matches the desired option and then again with Keys.Enter to submit the text. You may need to add a wait after clicking the container to give the browser time to render the input field.

Answer (score 0):

XPath is case-sensitive:

```
<div id="ServiceTypeId_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 389px;">
<a class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">
<span>Choose an Option</span>
<div>
<b></b>
</div>
```

id="ServiceTypeId_chzn"

//div[@**Id**='ServiceTypeId_chzn']

Should be: //div[@**id**='ServiceTypeId_chzn']

Comment: I am writing it with C#

Comment: What does that have to do with your XPath? It's still wrong.